# JQuery .each() loop truncating last value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select menu that has multiple select enabled.  I have a click event handler set for the submit button, so that jQuery loops through each drop down value selected and makes an ajax call.  It works fine, except for the very last value;  the last value in the list never seems to make it to the ajax call, and if only one item is selected, then there doesn't seem to any action.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$("#add_members").click(function () {
    var members = $("#project_members").val();

    jQuery.each(members, function () {
        var projectid = <? php echo $project_id; ?> ;
        var member = this[0];

        $.post([url], {
            project_id: projectid,
            user_id: member
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });

    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: It's more likely that none of the data is posted, because of `location.reload()`. When the document is being unloaded, every (AJAX) request is cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the others that you most likely have a race condition going on.  Your location.reload gets called directly after you last post and is most likely cancelling your ajax.

Try setting your ajax to not be asynchronous by using $.ajaxSetup

```
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async: false});   //set to false for this method

    $.post([url], {
        project_id: projectid,
            user_id: member
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
    });

    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async: true});   //Change it back when done if you so desire
```

This should end your race condition.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You've got a race situation.

Longer answer: The problem you're getting is because although `.each` is synchronous - meaning that all of the elements iterated by the each command are executed before a call to `location.reload()`. However `.post` is asynchronous - meaning that you cant guarantee that all posts have returned before exiting out of the each loop!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of working with $.each and selects: http://jsfiddle.net/7fhee/

The issue is most likely that you are expecting your ajax call to finish before you call location.reload(), which is probably not going to the be case. To fix the problem, you should perform the location.reload() in the success callback of your ajax calls.